# Moving mailitems from MAPIFolder to normal directory on Disc in zipped form

Tags: c#, zip, move, mapi, pst

I am trying to access individual mailitems from a .pst file in C#. I want to filter mails based on some input parameters. These filtered mails i want to zip and store in a particular location. i am able to filter mails based on the criteria but instead of moving the mails to particular destination folder i am able to move them only to MAPIFolder. Can anyone help?

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder destFolder = rootFolder.Folders["Test"];
((MailItem)item).Move(destFolder);
```

the above code i have implemented.
But i need something like

```
Folder destFolder = Path(@"C:\FilteredMails\");
((MailItem)item).Move(destFolder);
```

Kindly help.

Comment: You most probably need to use the `SaveAs` Method. It's VBA but maybe helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-saveas-method-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Call `MailItem.SaveAs(..., olMsg)` to save a message as an MSG file, then delete the message using `MailItem.Delete`.